# SQL - Calculated Column

Tags: sql, postgresql, calculated-columns

I have a table which shows me a stock ticker, asofdate, open, close.
I have created a computed column called daily PL which is simply the daily close-open.

```
,(close-open) AS daily_pl
```

I cannot figure out the logic of using the `{open}` from the first `asofdate` and the `{close}` from the most recent `asofdate`. and the table will naturally grow, so the logic needs to be dynamic. see below:

[image]

Comment: Not clear to me where you want to include this information?

Comment: I would either amend the daily_pl column or create a new column.

Comment: Why not just create a function that calculates that as needed in a query?

Comment: I’m 4 days into learning SQL, if you could show me how to calculate that, i would be very grateful.

Comment: I recommend updating the question to show the results you Want, rather than just the results you're currently getting. Then, explain the logic for each row. Pretend we don't know what you mean, and thst you need to demonstrate it in two or three ways.

Comment: Also, because you didn't include an ORDER BY, the row you highlighted isn't actually the last date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions. I think `first_value()` does what you want -- getting the first `open` price for the ticker:

```
select j.*,
       (close - first_value(open) over (partition by ticker order by asofdate) as daily_pl
from jandata j;
```

If you just want one row in the result set for each ticker, then you can use:

```
select distinct ticker,
       (first_value(close) over (partition by ticker order by asofdate desc) -
        first_value(open) over (partition by ticker order by asofdate)
       ) 
from jandata;
```